# Access Values from a customer table to a room type table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm Stuck in the middle of my MySQL project. Basically for now I have three tables `Room_Type`, `Room`, `Customer`. Read my code for `Room_Type` Table and in `Room` Table, there's a foreign key through which I can access its `room_type` (Standard, deluxe, etc) and in the `customer` table, there's a foreign key thorough which I can access `Room`. But My Issue is I want to access it's `room_Type` too through the `customer` Table and show it on the `customer` table. Can anyone here help me out. I'm really stuck here. Please correct me if I'm missing something, It would be a great help
Thanks in Advance

```
Create Table Room_Type
(
rt_ID int not NULL,
room_type nvarchar(50) not NULL,
Primary key(rt_ID),

);


Create Table Room
(
room_ID int not NULL,
r_Capacity int not NULL,
room_floor int not NULL,
r_price int not NULL,
rt_ID int not NULL,
Primary key(room_ID),
Foreign Key(rt_ID) references Room_Type(rt_ID)
);

insert into Room_Type Values
(1,'Standard'),
(2,'Superior'),
(3,'Deluxe')

insert into Room Values
(1,2,0,5000,1),
(2,3,0,6000,2),
(3,1,0,3000,2)

select Room.room_ID,Room.r_capacity,Room.room_floor,Room.r_price ,Room_Type.room_type from Room  inner join Room_Type  ON Room.rt_ID = Room_Type.rt_ID
*/

/*Customer*/
/*
Create Table Customer 
(
c_ID int not NULL,
c_name nvarchar (20) not NULL,
c_ph nvarchar(11)not NULL,
c_cnic nvarchar (13) not NULL,
c_address nvarchar (100) not NULL,
room_ID int NULL,

Primary Key(c_ID),
Foreign Key(room_ID) references Room(room_ID)
)


insert INTO Customer (c_ID,c_name,c_PH,c_cnic,c_address) Values
(1,'Hamza','337492379','327623862','ABC123');
insert INTO Customer  Values
(2,'Saleem','347934723','34567890123','XYZ321',1)
```

Comment: So your customers aren't supposed to ever come back, are they? Or in other words, if a customer has already rented a room once and then rents another room, how would you store that? Even if they rented the same room again, how would you distinguish the two different stays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to access it's room_Type too through the customer Table and show it on the customer table

You can join twice:

```
select c.*, rt.room_type 
from customer c
inner join room r on r.room_id = c.room_id
inner join room_type rt on rt.rt_id = r.rt_id
```

Comment: @HamzaSaleem: there was a typo in one of the join conditions. Fixed.

Comment: select c.*, rt.room_type 
from customer c
inner join room r on c.room_ID = r.room_ID
inner join room_type rt on rt.rt_id = r.rt_id